# HttpGet call using authentication

Tags: java, android, http

I am new to android and java development. I am trying to make a GET request to an API(providing username and password) and displaying the results in the log.

This is my work so far:

```
package com.example.android.d1;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.http.HttpException;
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.CredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String username = "xxxx";
        String password = "xxxxxxxx";
        String hostname = "xxxxx.service-now.com";

        CredentialsProvider provider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password);
        provider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(new HttpHost(hostname)), credentials);
        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(provider)
                .build();

        String query = "https://xxxxx.service-now.com/api/now/table/incident?sysparm_limit=1";

        try {
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(query);
            httpget.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            System.out.println("Executing request " + httpget.getRequestLine());
            CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            try {
                System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
                System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
                String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                System.out.println(responseBody);
            }
            finally {
                response.close();
            }
        } finally {
            httpclient.close();
        }
    }
}
```

This code is referenced from the documentation [here](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/geneva-servicenow-platform/page/integrate/inbound_rest/reference/r_TableAPIJavaExamples.html).

This is build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.d1"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation files('libs/commons-cli-1.2.jar')
    implementation files('libs/commons-codec-1.10.jar')
    implementation files('libs/commons-logging-1.2.jar')
    implementation files('libs/fluent-hc-4.5.6.jar')
    implementation files('libs/httpclient-4.5.6.jar')
    implementation files('libs/httpclient-cache-4.5.6.jar')
    implementation files('libs/httpclient-win-4.5.6.jar')
    implementation files('libs/httpcore-4.4.10.jar')
    implementation files('libs/httpcore-ab-4.4.10.jar')
    implementation files('libs/httpcore-nio-4.4.10.jar')
    implementation files('libs/httpmime-4.5.6.jar')
    implementation files('libs/jna-4.4.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/jna-platform-4.4.0.jar')
}
```

I am getting compilation errors like `error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown`.

Can anyone help in dealing with such situations? Also is there any way to make a GET request like this in a more better manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, I just realized that this is a code for a `Java` application and not suitable for an Android application.

You can try [this(Android official documentation)](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple) and [this(recommended)](https://www.journaldev.com/17198/android-volley-tutorial)

Anyway, to answer the question ::
Replace your code with this

```
try {
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(query);
        httpget.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        System.out.println("Executing request " + httpget.getRequestLine());
        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        try {
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
            System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
            String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            System.out.println(responseBody);
        }catch(Exception e){   //Not really necessary
            e.printStackTrace();  //Prints the exception in the logs
        }
        finally {
            response.close();
        }
    }catch(IOException e){  
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
     finally {
        httpclient.close();
    }
```

You need to catch the Exception being thrown by your code. 
It's called [ExceptionHandling](https://www.journaldev.com/1696/exception-handling-in-java)

You see, you are trying to make an Http network request and that "Network Request" might throw an error. So just to be safe, we are supposed to catch the exception.

Don't forget to import your `IOException`

```
import java.io.IOException;
```

Comment: I made changes to the code as suggested. But now i am getting another error.  `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method <init>(Lorg/apache/http/HttpHost;)V in class Lorg/apache/http/auth/AuthScope; or its super classes (declaration of 'org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope' appears in /system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar)
        at com.example.android.d1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)` 
 I have even added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Did you put the package inside your `build.gradle` file?

Comment: I just wnat to tell you that this code will not work inside your AndroidApplication.
Check the updated answer

Comment: This code works fine as a standalone java program, but fails to run in android. So there is no way to do that?. I have to try OkHttp or Volley and also AsyncTask.

Comment: Yes, that's what I said in the answer :p, the set of packages used will also be different in case of Android

Comment: Did it using Volley library